# What css is required to get editor-label and editor-field displayed with a side by side layout?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

So the default MVC application has the following css (in Site.css) -

```
/* Styles for editor and display helpers
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.display-label,
.editor-label
{
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.display-field,
.editor-field
{
    margin:0.5em 0 0 0;
}

.text-box
{
    width: 30em;
}

.text-box.multi-line
{
    height: 6.5em;
}

.tri-state
{
    width: 6em;
}
```

What changes are required?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a css question. What you are seeking is the property called `display: inline-block`.

What this does it set the element as a block but does not put a page break after and before the element as `block` would do.

```
.display-field,
.editor-field
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0.5em 0 0 0;
}
```